# Can't install pysam with pip in Python 3.6

Tags: python, pip, installation, pysam

Macbook
Mac OSX 10.12.6
Python 3.6.2
cython 0.28.5
pip 18.0

I'm trying to install pysam:

```
pip3 install pysam
```

It keeps hitting an error at:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.6/htslib/cram
htslib/cram/cram_io.c:63:10: fatal error: 'os/lzma_stub.h' file not found
#include "os/lzma_stub.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Seems like [this issue](https://github.com/konradjk/exac_browser/issues/332), [this](https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam/issues/645), and [this](https://github.com/pysam-developers/pysam/issues/697) were version issues. But I've tried `pip3 install pysam==0.13` and `0.14` and `0.15` with the same results.

Suggestions?

I *really* don't want to deal with installing conda...

Answer (score 0):

My mistake! `pip3 install pysam==0.13` actually DOES work. Just leaving this here for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you are missing `lzma`, which is now part of `xz` library (https://tukaani.org/xz/). Install that and see if it works. In OSX, you can install it using homebrew: `brew install xz`.

Another option is to install `htslib` (http://www.htslib.org/download/), or samtools (can be found in the `htslib` url).